# Generate XSD for CXF webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, xsd, cxf

I've a CXF web service Java classes, I use Eclipse 3.5. I generated the service WSDL file, and it has the `<wsdl:types>`, but the client that I work for is asking for a separate XSD file, how can I generate it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JavaEE Eclipse (or added all relevant modules to another Eclipse version), right click the class containing your service implementation -> *Web Services* -> *Create Web Service*.

Everything should be okay with the default values, just make sure that the first page has the right service implementation class and the page *Apache CXF Web Service Java2WS Configuration* has the checkboxes *Generate WSDL* and *Generate sparate XSD* checked.